# Get data from database and PHP using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I want to send data from text input and set result (from database) into another inputs using Ajax

I've tried to parse result into JSON using json_encode(), for some reason it didn't work and as solution I created a div in the result PHP page which with it I get the div with content

index.php

```
    <div class="form-group col-4">
        <label for=""> Code:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="codecli" name="codecli" onkeyup="showinfoclient()" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group col-8 " id="mess">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="minfoclient">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for=""> Lastname:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for=""> Firstname:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

client.php
if ($_REQUEST['idcli']) {

```
  $idcli = strip_tags($_POST['idcli']);
  $iduser = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $clients = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE 
`Current_user`=$iduser AND `id_client`='$idcli'");

while($client = $clients->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <div class="minfoclient">
        
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-6">
                <label for=""> Lastname:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="nom" class="form-control form-control-sm namm"  name="lastname" value="<?=$client['lastname'];?>">
            </div>

        <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for=""> Firstname:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text"  id="prenom" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="firstname" value="<?=$client['firstname'];?>">
        </div>

    </div> ...
```

this code worked but not as expected because it blocks other tasks

```
function showeinfoclient(){
  var iDClient = $('#codecli').val();
  if (iDClient) {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'client.php',
      data:'idcli='+iDClient,
      success:function(data){
        $('.minfoclient').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

as solution I hope you provide a simple code (AJAX, JSON, and PHP)

Comment: pass `data` as  `data: { idcli :   iDClient}`,

Comment: @DevsiOdedra - The way the OP has done it is perfectly valid (as long as there's no  strange characters in `iDClient`)

Comment: I actually  don't really get what you're trying to do. Where is `client.php` and what does it contain/output? Also, you need to explain what actually happens when you try your code. Just saying "it didn't work" doesn't give us anything to go on.

Comment: Show us client.php

Comment: @MagnusEriksson when i tried to use json encode, in Ajax the code was like:
success: function(data){
$('#lastname').val(data.lastname);
}
i'm kinda new with ajax i can't tell for sue why i didn't work!

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code (including your attempt with an explanation what actually happened). Also, you show us some HTML and then `result.php` while your ajax code calls `client.php`. We need a proper explanation of your code, structure, issues and expected results.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson done!

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to share more info (like the things I've already asked for a couple of times), I'm out...

Comment: the code i wrote shows everything the client.php contains the div full with data from sql this div replaces the div in the index.php i want to replace this code with json_encode

Comment: You need to do something more with php and also ajax response. As i understand you need the ajax result into the input fields, am i right?, Just wait I'm posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In client.php

```
$response=array();

while($client = $clients->fetch_assoc()){
$response[]=$client;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

After that inside ajax response you have to make for loop for each the client info create input elements.

ajax response:-

```
success:function(data){
     var clients=$.parsJSON(data);
var htmlData="";
     if(client.length>0){

       for(i=0;i<client.length;i++){
             htmlData += "<input type='text' name='firstname' value='"+client[i].firstname+"'><br>";
             htmlData += "<input type='text' name='lastname' value='"+client[i].lastname+"'><br>";
       }
        $('.minfoclient').html(htmldata);
      }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

please update JS code and PHP code.

JS Code :

```
function showinfoclient(){
  var iDClient = $('#codecli').val();

    if (iDClient) {
        $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'client.php',
        data:JSON.stringify(iDClient),
        dataType:'json', 

        })
        .done(function( json ) { 

            $('#lastname').val(json.lastname);
            $('#firstname').val(json.firstname);

        })
        .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {

          alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
          console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
          console.log( "Status: " + status );
          console.dir( xhr );
        });

    }
}
```

PHP Code (client.php):

```
$input = urldecode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$iDClient = json_decode($input,true);

// code to fetch firstname and lastname from database
$client = array('firstname' => 'John', 'lastname' => 'Doe'); // raw data


echo json_encode($client);
```

Comment: How could you possibly know what client.php contains? Especially since the OP identified the client.php is his code?

Comment: I just put raw data. OP should put his PHP code to fetch data from the database.